# Could not find required file in package createUiDefinition.json File path - Azure app publish in marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-marketplace

I have developed web app using `.NET Core 2.0`. Now I want to deploy this app in `Azure Marketplace` so anyone can use this app. To deploy the app I have created package which will contain below 2 files.

> 1. mainTemplate.json
> 2. createUIDefinition.json

And I have uploaded the package as shown in below image.
[image]
But it shows error:

> Package acceptance validation error: AzureAppAssetRequiredFileNotFound Could not find required file in package createUiDefinition.json File path: createUiDefinition.json Code: PAC-AzureAppAssetRequiredFileNotFound

I have tried to fix this issue but I was not able to make it work. Has anyone faced this issue or anyone know the solution please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this happens when your ZIP file contains folders, and in those folders you have the artifacts such as createUiDefinition.json.

To fix, make sure createUiDefinition.json is at the root of the ZIP archive and not in any subfolders.

Comment: Thanks, createUiDefinition.json is at the root of the ZIP worked